# Bootstrapping from CPS with weights

Tags: econometrics, empirical-methods, cps

I'm using CPS monthly individual data which comes with `wtfinl` as a float weight.

I'm computing some annual statistic for unemployed. I do that by

- Sum up `wtfinl` for all the unemployed observations for a given year
- Divide all `wtfinl` values by the annual sum, and then multiply the variable with this relative share

For example, if the variable is income, this gives me average income of unemployed.

Now, I would like to bootstrap the standard errors. I'm in Python. I

1. draw samples from the full annual table, each row with equal probability
2. Stop when number of rows is equal to the actual data
3. I then apply the same estimator as before to the sample, each row weighted with `wtfinl`

Now, when I compute the confidence bands, they're not centered around my actual estimator. Even worse, for one or two data points, the estimator is outside of the bands.

I suppose a alternative way to do the bootstrapping would be to

i. Draw from the annual table, each row with probability relative to `wtfinl/wtfinl.sum()`. 
ii. Stop drawing once `wtfinl.sum()` is equal to `wtfinl.sum()` in original data?
iii. Then do all the computations without using weights.

I thought my way was better because (a) I use the exactly same estimator both times without changing weights, and (b) it is clearer: How would I do (ii) exactly? When I have room for `wtfinl=1` left, do I only draw from rows with `wtfinl <= 1`?

However, given that my confidence bands dont line up with my original estimation, I'm befuddled. What should I do?